# Использовать метод другого класса

Tags: java, android

Как можно использовать метод getActivityInstance в классе который реализован в другом классе:

```
private Activity getActivityInstance(){
    getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Collection<Activity> resumedActivity = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
            for(Activity act : resumedActivity){
                currentActivity = act;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return currentActivity;
}
```

Comment: Вы о вложенных классах спрашиваете? Или о том, можно ли использовать приватный метод класса с помощью рефлексии?

Answer (score 1):

Можно вынести в класс `Application`

```
public class YourApp extends Application {

    ...

    public Activity getActivityInstance(){
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Collection<Activity> resumedActivity = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
                for(Activity act : resumedActivity){
                    currentActivity = act;
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return currentActivity;
    }

    ...
}
```

Вызов из любого места в активности:

```
((YourApp) YourActivity.this.getApplication()).getActivityInstance();
```

**P.S** не очень понятно для каких целей нужен данный метод, судя по всему он возвращает текущую активность, которая и так должна быть доступна "из любого места"

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать при использовании наследования.
Вот ссылка на похожий вопрос у меня. Хотя там о C++ но, объекты они и в африке объекты. Прочитайте о наследовании в языке java. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759559/arduino-использовать-методы-одной-библиотеки-в-другой/761042#761042](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759559/arduino-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9/761042#761042)

Пример из моего вопроса:

В файле (файл наследника) "RF24E.h" надо написать:

```
//указать что RF24E наследуется от RF24  символом ":"
 class RF24E : public RF24 //слово public разрешает вызывать (из файла ".ino") методы родителя так как будто это методы наследника
        {
          ... //здесь будут глобальные переменные наследника (они "private")
          public:
          //так как родитель имеет два типа конструктора, надо указать оба, иначе вызывается только конструктор по умолчанию (default constructor)
          //Заметьте что, тип переменных указывается лишь в наследующем конструкторе    

          //первый конструктор.
          RF24E(uint16_t _cepin, uint16_t _cspin) : RF24(_cepin, _cspin) {/*тут у 
          меня пусто*/};  

          //второй конструктор
          RF24E(uint16_t _cepin, uint16_t _cspin, uint32_t spispeed) : RF24(_cepin, 
          _cspin, spispeed) {};
         ... //тут будут методы наследника
        }
```

В основном коде, методы родителя выхываются так как-будто они являются методами наследника.